# How do I use Linq to get multiple values from a list inside a dictionary

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary

I've been trying for a bit but seem to be running into error after error, is there a way I can use Linq to compact this to make it more efficient, specifically the part where the dictionary list tries to detect if the list contains the intand returning it?

I'm sure its possible I just need a little help as I'm not so great with linq. If there's anything else you see I can do better I'd love to hear it. **This is just some test code I've isolated for a bigger piece**. Thanks in advance.

```
public enum columns { Parts_Column, Questions_Column, Answers_Column, Reset_Amount };
public static void Main()
{
    // Were are not comparing numbers this is just to fill the list out for count
    List<string> orderedRects = new List<string>() { "item1","item2","item3","item4","item5","item6","item7","item8","item9","item10" };

    Dictionary<columns, List<int>> TheDictionary = new Dictionary<columns, List<int>>();
    TheDictionary.Add(columns.Parts_Column, new List<int>() { 1 } );
    TheDictionary.Add(columns.Questions_Column, new List<int>() { 2, 4 } );
    TheDictionary.Add(columns.Answers_Column, new List<int>() { 3, 5 } );
    TheDictionary.Add(columns.Reset_Amount, new List<int>() { 6 } );
    
    int count = 0;
    int reset = TheDictionary[columns.Reset_Amount][0];
    for(int i = 0; i < orderedRects.Count;i++)
    {
        if(count == reset)
        {
            count = 0;
        }
        // Can we get this to become more compact using linq? or even combine them so each part has multiple int returns
        foreach (var pair in TheDictionary)
        {
            if(pair.Value.Contains(count))
            {
                int num = pair.Value.Where(o => o == count).FirstOrDefault();
                Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + ": " + num);
            }
        }
        count++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Total: " + count);
}
```

Comment: well, the Q in LINQ stands for **query**. However you actually don't query your list, but just do something on their elements, in particular execute an action for every element. So you won't gain much by using any linq here - you can of course.

Comment: `foreach (var pair in TheDictionary.Where(x => x.Value.Contains(count))) { Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + @": " + pair.Value.FirstOrDefault(o => o == count)); }`

Comment: Depends ... you could at least combine a Select and Where
- `Where` to get only `pair`s  whose has value is equal to `count`
- combine it with a `.AsParallel()` in order to parallelize the search part

Comment: I have not tested this but theoretically you could do it with a .Where and a .Select but the .Select would serve no purpose aside from being used to execute the code.  
`_ = TheDictionary.Where(pair => pair.Value.Contains(count)).Select(pair => { Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + @": " + pair.Value.FirstOrDefault(o => o == count)); return true; });`

Your original code is fine and the only "improvement" at least for clarity would be to add the .Where clause as seen in my previous comment.

Comment: @Nope is there a way I could get them in groups? Currently is outputs
Parts_Column: 1
Questions_Column: 2
Answers_Column: 3
Questions_Column: 4
Can we get this to Questions_Column: 2,4 or even return it as a list?

Comment: List<string. results = TheDictionary[Parts_Column];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets what I was looking for thanks for the replies.

```
public enum columns { Parts_Column, Questions_Column, Answers_Column, Reset_Amount };
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Were are not comparing numbers this is just to fill the list out
        List<string> orderedRects = new List<string>() { "item1","item2","item3","item4","item5","item6" };
        Dictionary<columns, List<int>> TheDictionary = new Dictionary<columns, List<int>>();
        TheDictionary.Add(columns.Parts_Column, new List<int>() { 1 } );
        TheDictionary.Add(columns.Questions_Column, new List<int>() { 2, 4 } );
        TheDictionary.Add(columns.Answers_Column, new List<int>() { 3, 5 } );
        TheDictionary.Add(columns.Reset_Amount, new List<int>() { 6 } );
        
        int count = 0;
        int reset = TheDictionary[columns.Reset_Amount][0];
        
        List<int> PartsColumnResults = new List<int>();
        List<int> QuestionsColumnResults = new List<int>();
        List<int> AnswersColumnResults = new List<int>();
        for(int i = 0; i < orderedRects.Count;i++)
        {
            if(count == reset)
            {
                count = 0;
            }
            foreach (var pair in TheDictionary.Where(x => x.Value.Contains(count))) 
            {
                // Parts Column
                if(pair.Key.Equals(columns.Parts_Column)) { PartsColumnResults = TheDictionary[columns.Parts_Column]; }
                // Questions Column
                if(pair.Key.Equals(columns.Questions_Column)) { QuestionsColumnResults = TheDictionary[columns.Questions_Column]; }
                // Answers Column
                if(pair.Key.Equals(columns.Answers_Column)) { AnswersColumnResults = TheDictionary[columns.Answers_Column]; }
            }
            count++;
        }
        foreach(var r in QuestionsColumnResults)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(r);
        }
    }
```